# Babel не компилирует мой js код

Tags: javascript, babel

В старых версиях IE не работает js код. Пытаюсь работать через babel.js. Создал в исходной папке проекта файл index.js. Прописал команды в командной строке: npm init, npm install --save-dev babel-cli babel-preset-env. В package.json в раздел scripts прописал "babel": "babel". Далее создал в корне проекта файл .babelrc и добавил { "presets": ["env"] } в него. Далее прописываю npm run babel --preset env index.js -o bundle.js. Babel для отдельных фрагментов кода не работает:

```js
class Spinner extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div id="spinner" className="position-absolute w-100 h-100 bg-dark" style={{ top: 0, left: 0 }}>
            <i className="fas fa-3x fa-sync-alt fa-spin text-light position-absolute" style={{ top: "50%", left: "50%" }}></i>
        </div>;
    }
}

let sum = 0;
let items = cart.items.map((item, index, arr) => {
    sum += item.price * item.count;
    return { ...item, sum: item.price * item.count, selected: false };
});
```

На сайте babel в разделе "Try it out" код корректно компилируется. В чем может быть ошибка?

P.S (Код не мой)

Comment: "Не компилирует" - это плохо. Хуже только не дать описание ошибки, с которой `Babel` отказывается делать свою работу.

Comment: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token. Ругается на символ < в первом выражении и на => во втором выражении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вашего js кода - в том, что он вовсе не js код, а jsx.

Для компиляции jsx вы должны добавить пресет react из пакета babel-preset-react.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, заработало!